# How to create a drop-down menu with database objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to make a website with many categories. I want staff to be able to add categories via the back-end admin page. Then I need to display those categories and display them to the to the user on a drop-down menu. They will then select a category and submit the result. All I need help with is the models.

```
#for back end
class create_listing_category(models.Model):
 category = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20)

categories = ???

class create_listing_sub_category(models.Model):     
 category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=categories) #categories will be the list contents
 sub_category = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=20)
```

**Thank you for helping your fellow noob out**

Comment: create relation model in one you will collect new category and in another you will access them.

Comment: Tried playing around with relational models. Didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self relation in your model

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

More info: https://djangopy.org/how-to/how-to-implement-categories-in-django/